# How to execute mysql command inside an if-then-else block that falls in a certain if-condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a MySQL table named 'tbl_sales_details' as 'table1'

```
___________________________
| tbl_sales_details        |
___________________________
| sales_id   PK varchar(20)|
| product_code varchar(20) |
| Qty  INT                 |
| Amount DOUBLE            |
____________________________
```

also i have a table named 'tbl_return_sales_details' as 'table2'

```
___________________________
| tbl_return_sales_details|
___________________________
| return_id  varchar(20)   |
| sales_id   FK varchar(20)|
| product_code varchar(20) |
| returned_Qty  INT        |
| returned_Amount DOUBLE   |
____________________________
```

Now what i want to achieved is:

1. Whenever there a new inserted data in  table2, with same sales_id and product_code executes: `UPDATE table1 set qty = qty - NEW.returned_qty WHERE sales_id = NEW.sales_id AND product_code = NEW.product_code`
2. But if the returned_qty (from table2) is equal to the qty (from table1)
   executes: `delete from table1 where sales_id = NEW.sales_id AND product_code = NEW.product_code`
3. I have already my codes that I started but there is an error on the syntax.

```
CREATE TRIGGER table2_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare sales_qty int;
    declare return_qty int;
    set sales_qty = (select qty from tbl_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id);
    set return_qty = (select returned_qty from tbl_returned_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id);
    if (sales_qty = return_qty)
    then
        delete from tbl_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id;
    else
        update tbl_sales_details set qty = qty - returned_qty, amount = amount - returned_amount where sales_id = new.sales_id;
    end if;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my own question.
I just added prefix "`new`" on "`returned_qty`". resulting to "`new.returned_qty`"
in MySQL trigger there is a rule about adding "new" or "old" see [25.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html#:%7E:text=Within%20the%20trigger%20body%2C%20the,there%20is%20no%20old%20row.)
and that solves my problem

```
begin
declare sales_qty int;
    declare return_qty int;
    set sales_qty = (select qty from tbl_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id);
    set return_qty = (select returned_qty from tbl_returned_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id);
    
    if(sales_qty = return_qty) then
        DELETE from tbl_sales_details where sales_id = new.sales_id;
    else
        update tbl_sales_details set qty = qty-new.returned_qty, amount = amount- new.returned_amount where sales_id = new.sales_id;
    end if;
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).